# What is Landscape for?

Tags: 14.04, landscape

What is Landscape for?

Apparently this service has been installed automatically with my Trusty Tar. Is it important for basic services such as Email, writing and printing a document, surfing the net and burning a photo-CD once in a while?
From the tagline I have learnt that Landscape is Canonical's Ubuntu-centric systems management system, available in both SaaS and Dedicated Server versions.

Here arise the questions "Do I have / need a 'Ubuntu-centric systems management system' ?" and "How can I find out wether I have 'either' / 'or both of SaaS and Dedicated Server versions' on my system?"

Comment: How did you detect that the Landscape service has been installed?

Answer (score 4):

#### Do I need Landscape?

As long as you don't manage other machines, you don't need Landscape.

#### But I thought it was installed ...

Maybe you infer that you have it installed from seeing it in the system settings. However, it probably isn't installed. If you click on it, you'll be asked whether you want to install it.

If you saw it in the software center and it was marked as installed: Look closer. It's the package `landscape-client-ui-install` which is just a minuscule package which provides the installation of landscape.

#### Well, thanks, but how do I figure out how whether it actually is installed?

Just click on the Landscape button in the system settings and see whether you're asked to install it.